# Opacity is not getting applied to the WPF Popup control

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, opacity

```
Popup popUpControl = new Popup();

popUpControl.PlacementTarget = this; 
popUpControl.StaysOpen = true;
popUpControl.Child = new MyUserControl(); /// my user control 
popUpControl.Opacity = 0.5; // this code has no effect in the appearance of the popup
popUpControl.IsOpen = true;
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the opacity on the popup content.
So for your button have

```
popUp.Child = new Button() 
{
    Width = 300,
    Height = 50,
    Background = Brushes.Gray,
    Opacity = 0.5 // set opacity here
};
```

Answer (score 12):

You should Enable Popup to have Transparency. Add following line of code.

```
popUpControl.AllowsTransparency=true;
```

Comment: Hi Sasikumar,
Thanx for ur reply.. i hv tried but still not working..

please put this following code in a wpf test app and see,
Popup poUp = new Popup();
            poUp.PlacementTarget = this;
            poUp.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.MousePoint;
            poUp.StaysOpen = true;
            poUp.PopupAnimation = PopupAnimation.Scroll;
            poUp.VerticalOffset = 52;
            poUp.HorizontalOffset = 5;
            poUp.Child = new Button() { Width = 300, Height = 50, Background = Brushes.Gray};
            poUp.AllowsTransparency = true;

Comment: Jay is right. You need to specify Opacity on Content. Try to add a grid as child to popup and add all your controls in this grid. Configure Opacity of Grid to reflect it in its children.